# Connection Port for Java GridDB using java

Tags: java, ubuntu, griddb

I want to write an application in Java that accesses data from GridDB. In the documentation, I see the connection port defaults to 31999. By coincidence, I already have an application running on this port. Is it possible to change the default connection port in GridDB? How would I do this? Thanks

I tried going through the installation guide, but can't find anything to tell me how to change the port.

Comment: According, to documentation [portNo: Port number used in connecting with a GridDB cluster. (Default: 41999)](https://docs.griddb.net/v4.5/jdbcdriver/overview/#connection-url-format)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this manual: https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v5_2/GridDB_AdministratorsGuide.html#multicast-method

31999 is the transaction port if you select multicast as the communication method. If you go with fixed list the default port is 10001. You can change the port number by editing gs_cluster.json